# jar build using maven showing error

Tags: java, maven, jar, pom.xml

i have build an application that fetch the value from `Count` tag of some xml files and writes it to the output excel XLSX file.

i have 2 functions in my program which are called by `main()`. First is `readXml()` which read the xml files and second is `writeXlsx()` which writes to the output excel file.

i have used maven to add dependencies and build jar file.

when i run the created jar, it works well for half of the program but gives an error when try to write XLSX. Error comes up is :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/poi/xssf/usermodel/XSSFWorkbook
    at com.mpstddn.App.writeXLSX(App.java:107)
    at com.mpstddn.App.main(App.java:64)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook
```

same program works well when i run it from eclipse but gives error when i make a jar of it and run it. It seems to me that jar is not able to include the apache poi lib. I am new to maven and don't know where i am making mistake. here is my `pom.xml` :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.mpstddn.java</groupId>
    <artifactId>myMavenProject</artifactId>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>myMaven</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>
       <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.15</version>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>javax.jms</groupId>
                <artifactId>jms</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jmx</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxri</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>com.sun.jdmk</groupId>
                <artifactId>jmxtools</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>openxml4j</artifactId>
          <version>1.0-beta</version>
      </dependency>     
       <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
          <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
            <version>3.9</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
            <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
            <version>3.10-FINAL</version>
        </dependency>
     </dependencies>
    <build>
        <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
        <scriptSourceDirectory>src\main\scripts</scriptSourceDirectory>
        <testSourceDirectory>src\test\java</testSourceDirectory>
        <outputDirectory>target\classes</outputDirectory>
        <testOutputDirectory>target\test-classes</testOutputDirectory>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <directory>src</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <directory>lib</directory>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.jar</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
 </resources>
 <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2-beta-5</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.1</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-release-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0</version>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
 </pluginManagement>
  <plugins>
        <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                        <archive>
                                <manifest>
                                        <mainClass>com.mpstddn.App</mainClass>
                                </manifest>
                        </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
       <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testCompile</id>
                    <phase>test-compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testCompile</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-compile</id>
                    <phase>compile</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>compile</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <source>1.7</source>
                        <target>1.7</target>
                        <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-clean</id>
                    <phase>clean</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>clean</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-install</id>
                    <phase>install</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>install</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-resources</id>
                    <phase>process-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>resources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-testResources</id>
                    <phase>process-test-resources</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>testResources</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.10</version>
            <executions>
                  <execution>
                    <id>default-test</id>
                      <phase>test</phase>
                     <goals>
                        <goal>test</goal>
                     </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
             <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                     <manifest>
                         <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
                                <classpathPrefix>lib/</classpathPrefix>
                             <mainClass>com.mpstddn.App</mainClass>
                      </manifest>
                 </archive>
            </configuration>
             <executions>
                <execution>
                     <id>default-jar</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <configuration>
                        <packagingExcludes>*.jar</packagingExcludes>
                    </configuration>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>jar</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.7</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <phase>deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
         </plugin>
         <plugin>
          <artifactId>maven-site-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-site</id>
                    <phase>site</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>site</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target\site</outputDirectory>
                        <reportPlugins>
                            <reportPlugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            </reportPlugin>
                        </reportPlugins>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-deploy</id>
                    <phase>site-deploy</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>deploy</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <outputDirectory>target\site</outputDirectory>
                        <reportPlugins>
                            <reportPlugin>
                                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                                <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                            </reportPlugin>
                        </reportPlugins>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
            <configuration>
                <outputDirectory>target\site</outputDirectory>
                <reportPlugins>
                    <reportPlugin>
                        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                        <artifactId>maven-project-info-reports-plugin</artifactId>
                    </reportPlugin>
                </reportPlugins>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
       </plugins>
     </build>
 </project>
```

The way I create the jar :
`right click on project in eclipse -> run as -> Maven install`
this create a jar file in `target` directory inside project folder.

I am running the jar file using command prompt by typing :

```
java -jar myMavenProject-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar X:\input_directory input.xml 9
```

Comment: Did you set your runtime classpath (when you launch your jar)? You should edit and tell us how you "run"

Comment: org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook should be poi-ooxml - hard to say why its not found. As mentioned in the comment above the way you run the thing to get to your error is probably the way to investigate.

Comment: How are you creating the jar?

Comment: Hm... from a quick look your maven configuration seems to be o.k. and the dependency should be packed into your .jar. Is this the case? The only thing i currently dont know is on how your resources definition will behave

Comment: @RC. What makes you guys think that this should be an issue? If you ask me the way he has defined his dependencies they will have the 'compile' scope applied by default and according dependencies (jars) will be packed into his jar.

Comment: If the project is exported as a runnable jar from Eclipse, won't it required the build path to point to the required jars?

Comment: Why have you changed default folder layout? Never use '\' in maven poms...

Comment: @RC. Sorry for late response and thank you very much for your kind reply. I have added the information regarding how I am creating the Jar file and how i am running it. I am not using run time classpath. Is it necessary ?

Comment: @user1902288 Exactly this should be the case. But I think dependency is not getting packed into my Jar.

Comment: My advice: don't assume, be sure. So remove all plugins you don't need/know from your build, read the documentation of the one you need, find out which one is in charge of doing your "jar with dependencies" (that's not a default feature) and cross check its configuration

Comment: @PARITOSHTHAPLIYAL Since i am not a Maven guru too i cant help anymore but sign the recommendation of RC. I would try to remove any plugin configurations, exclusions and stuff you are not absolutly aware of you need and want them. Maybe start by having a very simple Maven Project from Scratch since this would defently pack the jars into your archive. I can only guess that it is either one of your exclusions or a unlucky combination of your exclusions but this is only guessing.

Comment: @PARITOSHTHAPLIYAL I would comment out all of those exclusions and plugin configurations regarding the maven lifecycle phases because i guess the worst that can happen is that there are too many things beeing packed into your archive (like additional .jars from a /lib folder). (Of couse once there is too many things in your archive you will start to care on how to get rid of them again)

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is not based on a dependency it's because you configured maven-assembly-plugin wrong:

```xml
<project>
  [...]
  <build>
    [...]
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <configuration>
          <descriptorRefs>
            <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
          </descriptorRefs>
        </configuration>
        <executions>
          <execution>
           <id>package</id>
           <goals>
             <goal>single</goal>
           <goals>
           <phase>package</phase>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
 </build>
</project>
```

The problem is that maven-assembly-plugin does not bind by default to any life cycle phase. Afterwards try:

```
mvn clean package
```

And check the resulting jar file (`target/WhatEver-x.x-SNAPSHOT-jar-with-dependencies.jar`).

Comment: @khmarbaise I already have added this dependency but I think this dependency is not getting packed into the jar I am creating.